# How to Return JTable Cell Value From Class A to Class B

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe

I would like to know why I am getting a `NullPointerException` when I am trying to return `JTable` cell value from class A to class B.

[Class A's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfIIW.png)

[Class B's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbEKV.png)

Any valuable feedback or suggestions to overcome the issue are highly appreciated!

Comment: please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

btw, the exception tells you exactly what the error is... in the line (mentioned in the "exception text"), something is null

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)